# bad deformations

Tags: rigging

I am currently having a problem with deformations. I am relatively new to Blender and this work is my first one so I do have a lot of knowlege issues here.

In the scrrenshot I am trying to rotate the arm on the local y axis that leads to terrible bad deformations.

[image]

I used this tutorial as a startup point to get the arm rotation working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P81DGubVILA
In the tutorial there are 3 bones used to rotate the arm. This led to an even worse result so I tried it with 4 bones which is slightly better but still horrible. Is there any specific trick to this that I do not know? Does this result from bad weight-painting? I simply do not know where to search to solve the issue.
I also have a similiar issue with the face when I try to open the mouth. Some edges of the cheeks are getting distorted in this case on higher resolutions: Unfortunately I deleted the bones and forgot to make a screenshot but the following screenshot will show the edges that are pushed in. Its only by a little but it ruins the face completely.
[image]

what can I do to avoid such things?
May it be that this problem is a result to bad retopology?

EDIT:
Blend-file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v687nqa4b0mgquy/rhin13.blend?dl=0

Comment: i can only recommend watching beginner tutorials about rigging in which the guy who made the tutorial explains what he does and why that works. Don't watch tutorials without explanation. That's a waste of time. Especially for beginners. And there are tons of good tutorials out there. For free. But please edit your question and show us your bad deformation - because i don't see it. And pls provide blend file.

Comment: the bad deformation is in the red circle. I get fragments in the mesh based on the rotation that look really weird.
I would provide the .blend file if I knew how. There is no file upload functionality here...

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: was not able to upload to blend-exchange.com. The xhr-request to the server hang itself for some reason. Therefore I provided a dropbox link where I uploaded the file.